# Is there a way to create folders and reports through API?

Tags: rest-api, api

Is there a way to create folders and reports through API?

else

How can I create reports programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create reports and folders by way of the [Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/). There is both a file-based API and a REST-based API to suit your needs.

Comment: thank you, I reviewed the Metadata API and now I'm able to create a simple custom object, but i can't figure out how to create a report. Could you please give me more information related to it?

Comment: And yes, Metadata API is the right place to do it. http://www.pocketsoap.com/weblog/2008/10/1826.html I found this documentation very useful. Now I'm able to get a zip file containing the reports of a Folder. Thank you sdcfox